# php bin2hex() decode back in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, hex, ascii

i have a url in an database and will be encode that with the php function bin2hex(). I want to decode that back in javascript

Both function give exact the same output. But what function is better, faster and more reliable? Because it must work on all desktop and mobile devices.

```
function first_HexToString(input) {
    var result = "";

    for(q = 0; q < input.length; q += 2) {
        result += '%' + input.substr(q,2);
    }

    return decodeURIComponent(result);
}

function second_HexToString(input) {
    var result = "";

    for(q = 0; q < input.length; q += 2) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input.substr(q,2),16));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Ps; the url is not very very secret and will be  shown simple in Firebug or something like that, i goes about the idea that it is possible to encode the url. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, I'd go with the first function, as it has fewer method calls: input.length*3/2+1, versus input.length*2 that the second one has.

Computation details:

- first function will do 3 function calls: two concatenations, one substr() per iteration step, to which we add the final decodeURIComponent() call
- second function will do 3 function calls, plus one concatenation, resulting 4 function calls per iteration steps
- now we have str.length/2 iteration steps, which give the mentioned result

Comment: what do you think about decodeURIComponent complexity?

Comment: The performance of decodeURIComponent() is negligible, and will likely consist in a similar algorithm as function #2, only natively implemented, which can benefit of pre-allocated string and much faster function calls, compared to the 3 embedded one from function #2

Answer (score -1):

Is the performance of decodeURIComponent() is negligible then is this also possible. Ha!

```
function third_HexToString(input) {
  return decodeURIComponent(input.replace(/(.{1,2})/g, "%$1"));
}
```